# How do I make a crypto browser extension like metamask?

Tags: metamask

I want to create a browser extension like [Metamask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension) that can sign transactions, so that I can use my browser extension to make swaps on DEXs and buy NFTs.

Is there a starting point for how to do this? I already have an idea how to make a browser extension. I'm wondering how to go about making it such that when I click on Connect Wallet, it triggers my browser extension to popup similar to how it works for Tally?

[Tally](https://github.com/tallycash/extension) is an extension that works similar, when you perform an action that would have triggered Metamask. Tally popsup instead.

Update: [This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/building-your-own-web3-provider) is similar to what I'm trying to do. "Create a custom window.ethereum javascript provider". As defined in [EIP-1193](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193).